# Gradient Color in layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to know how I can set gradient color in my layout. I want to start with dark green from left side and become lighter to center and from center to right that color should be become darker. How I can do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create one selector file and put in drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:startColor="#FFFF0000"
            android:centerColor="#0000FFFF" 
            android:endColor="#FF00FF00"
            android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
```

Change color as per your requirement. Change angel as per your requirement also.

[Look Here](http://www.dibbus.com/2011/02/gradient-buttons-for-android/) for more details.Choose Your Green Color code from here .
http://www.december.com/html/spec/color2.html

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a shape drawable as specified here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#000"
        android:startColor="#fff"
        android:type="linear/>
</shape>
```

Comment: I guess you can add the "android:centerColor" attribute to get the desired effect.

Comment: I agree with you Ruben. centerColor attribute is the key for the desired effect.